# War proguard does not contain jar file of the project

Tags: proguard, war, obfuscation

I am trying to obfuscate a war project. I know that when you obfuscate a war project, you can find a jar file of the project in `WEB-INF/lib` and I could find this jar when I obfuscated my project a few months back. But when I obfuscate it now, I cannot find the jar file, so the project does not deploy on tomcat.

Any ideas?

Here is my proguard config file:

```
-injars /target/project-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
-outjars /target/project.war
-dontwarn
-optimizations !class/marking/final
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/spring.*,spring/*
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod 
-allowaccessmodification
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontnote
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-keepdirectories

   -keep class org.springframework.** { *; }
   -keep @javax.annotation.Resource class *
   -keep @org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching class *
   -keep public class * implements javax.servlet.Servlet
   -keep class com.zaxxer.hikari.** {*;}
   -keep class  javax.el.Expression {*;}
   -keep class javax.** { *; }
   -keep class javax.validation.** {*;}
   -keep class java.** { *; }
   -keep class org.primefaces.** {*;}
   -keep class org.** { *; }
   -keep class javassist.** { *; }
   -keep class cglib.** {*;}
   -keep class io.jsonwebtoken.** {*;}
   -keep class io.swagger.** {*;}
   -keep class com.fasterxml.** {*;}
   -keep class com.sun.** {*;}
   -keep class dom4j.** {*;}
   -keep class antlr.** {*;}
   -keep class mysql.mysql-connector-java.** {*;}
   -keep class com.mysql.jdbc.** {*;}
   -keep class com.mysql.cj.core.** {*;}
   -keep class com.mysql.cj.api.** {*;}
   -keep class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.** {*;}
   -keep class com.mysql.cj.mysqla.** {*;}
   -keep class com.mysql.cj.mysqlx.protobuf.MysqlxDatatypes$Any {*;}
   -keep public class com.mysql.cj.mysqlx.** {*;}
   -keep class * implements java.sql.Driver 
   -keep class com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory {*;}
   -keep class com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream {*;}
   -keep class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite {*;}
   -keep class com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage {*;}
   -keep class com.google.protobuf.MysqlxDatatypes$Object$Builder {*;}
   -keep class com.google.protobuf.MysqlxDatatypes$Array$Builder {*;}
   -keep class edu.vt.middleware.vt-password.** {*;}
   -keep class junit.junit.** {*;}
   -keep class io.netty.netty-all.** {*;}
   -keep class commons-dbcp.commons-dbcp.** {*;}
   -keep class org.apache.poi.poi.** {*;}
   -keep class com.google.code.gson.gson.** {*;}
   -keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.** {*;}
   -keep class com.sun.faces.** {*;}
   -keep class org.glassfish.web.el-impl.** {*;}
   -keep class postgresql.postgresql.** {*;}
   -keep class net.sf.jt400.jt400-full.** {*;}
   -keep class c3p0.c3p0.** {*;}
   -keep class com.lowagie.itext.** {*;}
   -keep class org.apache.xmlbeans.xmlbeans.** {*;}
   -keep class ojdbc.ojdbc.** {*;}
   -keep class oracle.jdbc.driver.** {*;}
   -keep class oracle.** {*;}
   -keep class edu.vt.middleware.** {*;}
   -keep class javax.faces.view.** {*;}
   -keep class org.omnifaces.omnifaces.** {*;}



    -keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.* *;
    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier *;
    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *;
    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required *;
    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean *;
    @javax.annotation.PostConstruct *;
    @javax.annotation.PreDestroy *;
    @org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning *;
    @org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut *;
    @org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing *;
    @org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around *;
    @org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor *;
}



# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration
# classes.

-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
# You can comment this out if your library doesn't use serialization.
# If your code contains serializable classes that have to be backward
# compatible, please refer to the manual.

-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javax.annotation.Resource *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
 @javax.persistence.Id <fields>;
}
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keep @javax.persistence.* class * {
    *;
}

 -keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Service class *
 -keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Component class *
 -keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Controller class *
 -keep @com.scsoft.afc.utility.scope.SpringViewScoped class *

 -keep,allowobfuscation class com.test.** {*;}
   -keep class com.test.service.** {
     *;
  }
```

And here is my `<build>` section from `pom.xml`:

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.jar</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>log4j.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>war-exploded</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>war</id>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-install</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>proguard</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.bootstrap.classes}</lib>
                        <lib>${java.cryptographic.extension.classes}</lib>
                        <lib>${java.secure.socket.extension.classes}</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                    <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.1</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment

Comment: @Shailesh Java 8, spring security 4.2.3, primefaces 6.1 and JSF 2.2.14.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i was also interested how are you preparing war file, your build process and obfuscation process

Comment: @Shailesh I added my config to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using `attachClasses` while I needed to use `archiveClasses`. Now everything works like a charm.